# disabling form element

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want a button to be disabled when it is clicked. Here is my code:

```
var disable = function(form_name,btn_name) {
    document.form_name.btn_name.disabled = true;
}
```

This is how `disable()` is called:

```
<form name = 'form1'>
     <input name = 'btn1' type = 'button' disabled = false onclick = 'disable("form1","btn1")' />
</form>
```

This code does not work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Also, for the record, while I *always* put spaces around `=` in procedural languages, I have to say that having them in HTML the way you're doing is extremely painful to look at.

Comment: I think in some browsers the 'disabled = false' in your HTML will disable the button as it will read the 'disabled' attribute and ignore the '= false' bit. Probably safest to remove this.

Comment: @ipr101--thats exactly what happened. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

```
document.form_name.btn_name.disabled = true;
```

is the same as doing

```
document['form_name']['btn_name'].disabled = true;
```

You need to do

```
document[form_name][btn_name].disabled = true;
```

Comment: @chaose--Isn't that what I've done? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @codeninja: No, it isn't.  It seems you're under the impression that `obj.foo` and `obj[foo]` are the same; they aren't, and what I wrote above illustrates how they are different.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the dot notation with variable name, You should use the array notation:

```
var disable = function(form_name,btn_name) {
    document[form_name][btn_name]["disabled"] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just:

```
 onclick = 'this.disabled = true;'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
<form name='form1'>
     <input name='btn1' type='button' disabled='false' onclick='this.disabled = true' />
</form>
```